# Need help with updating a mysql table by a csv file upload

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Following is my script to upload the table employee with a csv file. The file is uploading and upldating the employee table perfectly. BUT the problem is i specified a row with headings in the csv file. That heading row is also getting updated in the table. I want only those datas to get uploaded except the heading row in the csv file, any help or ideas?.

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';

if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
$fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
$chk_file = explode(".",$fname);

if(strtolower($chk_file[1]) == 'csv')
{
$filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($filename,"r");

while(($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) != false)
{
$sql = "INSERT into   employee(employee_code,employee_name,employee_address,emp_dateofjoin,emp_designation,emp_hq,pf_num,esic_num,emp_state,month,tot_work_days,lop_days,arrear_amt,leave_encash) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]','$data[12]','$data[13]')";

/$upd = "UPDATE student SET   month='',tot_work_days='',lop_days='',arrear_amt='',leave_encash='' where  employee_code=''";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo "Successfully Imported";
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid File";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: You've given us the code that produces a CSV file. You did not share the code that processes an uploaded file. That's what you want help with, the code you are showing is not helpful.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I apologize for my blunder. Now i hav edited with the right code and hoping for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the first line by calling `fgetcsv` once before your loop:

```
fgetcsv($handle,1000,",");
while(($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) != false)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your timely help Dan, It worked perfectly. 1m reps to you..! :)

Answer (score 0):

You also could use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) MySQL statement with 'IGNORE 1 LINES' clause.